# Installing Modules in PHP 7

Tags: php, module, php-7

I have not been able to find a module for `sqlite` in `php7`. Does anyone know how to bypass this problem as it is annoying plus all my prototypes run on `sqlite`.

Is there a repository that will help out?

Comment: How'd you install PHP? Is there an `sqlite3` module?

Answer (score 6):

I found that the module names have changed. here is an article with a list of all the needed php modules [Article Link](http://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/#)

You can alternatively run to find more modules

> sudo apt-cache search php7-*